# Can I search filter through a child component? (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, pipe

I've got a parent component that I'm passing data down to a child component with *ngFor / @input. That child component is created x number of times depending on how many objects are in the pciData array

pciData is an array of about 700 data objects, all with a "hostname" property/value.  when passed down to app-system, the hostname of that object shows on a button. I want the end user to be able to filter through those buttons by that hostname, only showing the app-system components that match.

On the parent component template, how would I create a search bar that can filter the app-system components by their hostname property values?  In the code below, I've tried piping this like:

`<ng-container *ngFor="let system of pciData | searchFilter: system.hostname  | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 180, currentPage: p }; let i = index ">`

but "system" comes back undefined.   However, when I just type in {{system.hostname}} in the template under the loop, it does loop through every single object and display the hostname.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Here's the parent component. I've removed the implimentation that I tried to do with the filter to avoid confusion:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Ipcidata } from '../Shared/Ipcidata';
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-system-status',
  templateUrl: './system-status.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./system-status.component.css'],
})

export class SystemStatusComponent implements OnInit {


  @Input() pciData: any;



constructor() {}
  searchText;
  p: number;
  filteredValues : any;

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Here's the parent template, "app-system" is what I'm trying to search through the values of :

```
<ngx-spinner></ngx-spinner>

<section class="app-container">

  <div class ="card-container">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let system of pciData | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 180, 
      currentPage: p }; let i = index ">
      <div class='cardboi'>
        <app-system [systemInput]="system"></app-system>

      </div>
    </ng-container>  
  </div>
  <div class="pagination-container">
    <pagination-controls class='paginator' (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls> 
  </div>
</section>
```

lastly, here is the child template, to which the search bar filter should only show what the user inputs as the hostname. This is essentially just a button that pops up more data about that host when clicked. Again, the point of this is only to show the buttons with a certain hostname.

```
  <button  (click)="openDialog()" [ngClass]="{
    'btn buttonGood':isValid(),
    'btn buttonDateAlert':isValid()=='datewarning',
    'btn buttonAlert':isValid()==false
  }">{{systemInput.hostname.slice(0,13) | uppercase}}</button>

</div>
```

Thanks again for anyone who can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your *ngFor loop, the array you are looping though is being piped. The pipe has to be processed before the loop begins. So `pciData` is piped through the two pipes and then the resulting array is looped through. Which is why `system` doesn't exist at the time that the pipes are being processed.

My recommendation would be to not use a pipe for the search filters. Instead, create another pciData variable. You can call it something like `filteredPciData`. Bind to the onChange event of the search box in the parent component. When the search value changes, filter `pciData` (which should have all values) and use `filteredPciData` to store the results. Then in your HTML loop through `filteredPciData` instead of `pciData`

Comment: I was writing similar answer.

Comment: Thank you. This was simple to understand and you knew exactly what I needed based off my explanation. I'll give this a shot.    

As a follow up question... So any pipe will preform it's function before ngFor? So when used in conjunction, the pipes can't access the values since the array hasn't been looped through and assigned yet? (just making sure I understand correctly)